Why doesn't CSS nesting appended nesting selector work within pseudoselectors?
Why is the first div red, but not the other? If you enable SCSS preprocessor in the pen, both divs are red as expected.
https://codepen.io/aeharding/pen/wvVLBZg


.regular {
  html & {
    color: red;
  }
}

.pseudo:before {
  content: '(pseudo) style me red';

  html & {
    color: red;
  }
}
<div class="regular">(regular) style me red</div>

<div class="pseudo"></div>




It's by design but it may change in the future: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7433
From the actual Specification:

The nesting selector cannot represent pseudo-elements


Wow. It's crazy that such a huge gotcha was actually shipped with the spec lol



.regular {
  html & {
    color: red;
  }
}

.pseudo:before {
  content: '(pseudo) style me red';

  html & {
    color: red;
  }
}
<div class="regular">(regular) style me red</div>

<div class="pseudo"></div>




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
